# How to prove $\exp\in C^1(\mathcal{L}(E),\mathcal{L}(E))$？

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, functional-calculus

I'm working on Amann's *Analysis* exersice VII.3.8:

> Prove $\exp\in C^1(\mathcal{L}(E),\mathcal{L}(E))$ and $\partial\exp(0)=id_{\mathcal{L}(E)}$ .

Where $E$ is a Banach space, and $\mathcal{L}(E)$ is the bounded linear operator Banach algebra on $E$. The $\exp$ operator is defined by
$$\exp(A)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{A^k\over k!}.$$

My problem:

I don't even know how to calculate its derivative, though I know it should be a map from $\mathcal L(E)$ to $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{L}(E),\mathcal{L}(E))$. I guess there should be $\partial\exp(A)(X)=\exp(A)$, but I don't know why.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your question is solved in the comments to the answer of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825848/is-matrix-exponentiation-exp-mathcalle-to-mathcalle-continuously-fr%c3%a9?rq=1).

Comment: Your $\sum$ should begin at $k=0.$